# Delete rows If more than 5 colums are empty

Tags: excel

Hello I have an excel tabelle like this;(there are 80000 rows and 11 columns)

```
Name Lastname Email          question-1   question-2   question-3   question-4 question-5
Sam   Bob      s@gmail.com    a             b           c                       a    
Ally  ko       a@gmail.com    a                         c                       a
John  So       b@gmail.com    
marc  jo      c@gmail.com     a             b           c                       a
sarah du      sa@gmail.com
```

So my question is how can I delete automatically the rows that have no answer for questions

Comment: I would suggest adding a helper column which returns `TRUE` or `Yes` if the row is blank, then use a filter to filter your table to exclude rows that are blank.

Comment: This is a nice idea with helper column I can check if questions are filled but after that How can I automatically delete all the rows has true value?

Comment: To delete rows you'll have to use VBA. Are you open to VBA solution?

Answer (score 1):

To delete rows you'll have to use VBA. Try following.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6")  'change Sheet6 to your data sheet

    With ws
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lastRow
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("D" & i & ":H" & i), "") = 5 Then   'check if all 5 cells are empty
                If rng Is Nothing Then      'add cell to range
                    Set rng = .Range("a" & i)
                Else
                    Set rng = Union(rng, .Range("a" & i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        If Not rng Is Nothing Then
            rng.EntireRow.Delete    'delete entire row of cells in range
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

How to add above code in Excel file:

1. Open your workbook
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, to open the Visual Basic Editor
3. In `Insert` menu click `Module`
4. Copy above code and paste it on the right pane opened
5. To run the code click anywhere in the code and press <kbd>F5</kbd>

Comment: can`t I do it with excel? I have no idea where to copy this code

Comment: @kindaquestion - For `Copy Excel VBA Code to a Regular Module` see [this](http://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html).

Comment: @kindaquestion - If anything is not clear let me know.

Comment: @kindaquestion - See explanation in answer.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that it tells you which rows need deleting but doesn't actually delete them?

Comment: @TomSharpe - Oops! For testing I wrote `MsgBox...` and forgot to replace it with `...Delete` while uploading answer. Thanks for pointing it out, answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Mrig's answer is good for VBA solution. If you want to do it with a helper column and filtering, try this:

Add a new column and type this formula into cell `I2` (or whatever column is at the end of your data):

```
= AND(ISBLANK(D2:H2))
```

Also, you can change `D2:H2` above to whatever applies to your sheet. In my sheet, columns `D` through `H` correspond to the question 1 through question 5 columns.

Also, this is an array formula, so you will have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard instead of just <kbd>Enter</kbd> after typing in this formula.

**EDIT:** Another solution without array formula (courtesy of Mrig) is:

```
= COUNTA(D2:H2)=0
```

Drag this formula down for however many rows your data extends.

See below for an example.

[image]

Notice how `TRUE` appears in rows where all of the "question" columns are blank.

Next you can apply a filter to this data to include only those rows in the helper column where `FALSE` appears.

Comment: Instead of an array formula you can also use `=COUNTA(D2:H2)=0`

Comment: Thanks @Mrig. Clever workaround. I'll modify my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the two answers above, another way is to combine the two approaches suggested.

1) Create the helper formula in excel by inserting a column before the data with this equation (Drop it down through all cells):
    =IF(COUNTBLANK(E1:L1)>=5,TRUE, FALSE)

2) Click on the "Developer Tab" in Excel

3) Click Insert>Module

4) Paste this code:

```
Sub sbDelete_Rows_Based_On_Criteria()
Dim lRow As Long
Dim iCntr As Long
lRow = 8000000
For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
If Cells(iCntr, 1) = True Then
Rows(iCntr).Delete
End If
Next
End Sub
```

5) Save the file as .xlsm

6) Click Run/Sub User Form.

7) Click the excel icon on the top left and all the rows with >5 blanks will be gone.